# C Programing: File reader format conversion Error

Tags: c, file, debugging

I got

```
program.cpp: In function ‘int view_next(FILE*)’:
program.cpp:118: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘)’ in format
```

when I try to compile (`gcc -o program program.cpp`) but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please give me a hand?

```
printf("\033[7m--More--(%.0f%)\033[m", float(file_size) /
        float(buffIn.st_size) * 100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this:

```
 printf("\033[7m--More--(%.0f%)\033[m", float(file_size) /
```

should be:

```
 printf("\033[7m--More--(%.0f%%)\033[m", float(file_size) /
```

read (or google) `man 3 printf`

What is happening here, is that the `%` character is used in functions of the printf family to signal that a format specifier is following. To print a literal `%` character, you can escape it with another `%` character.

```
 printf("%%\n"); // prints a literal %
```

This is a minimal example that reproduces your error:

```
 printf("%)\n"); // errors
```

And here is the fix to the minimal example:

```
 printf("%%)\n"); // prints "%)"
```

Comment: Not everyone is using linux.